# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List<LangModel>>?'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I want to get a list of languages in my flutter app from my sqflite db, but when I try create the lang list i get this error type **'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future<List>?'**

I tried everything but nothing change, how can i solve the problem?

**lang_provider.dart**

```
class LangProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<LangModel> langs = [];

  Future<List<LangModel>> getAllLangs() async{
    Database db = await DBProvider.db.initDB();
    final result = await db.query('languages');

    return result.isNotEmpty ? result.map<LangModel>((langs) => LangModel.fromJson(langs)).toList() : [];
  }

  Future<LangModel?> getLangById(int id) async{
    Database db = await DBProvider.db.initDB();
    final result = await db.query('languages', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);

    return result.isNotEmpty ? LangModel.fromJson(result.first) : null;
  }

  loadLangs<LangModel>() async{
    final langs = await getAllLangs();
    this.langs = [...langs];
  }
}
```

**lang_list.dart**

```
    final langProvider = Provider.of<LangProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final langs = <LangModel>[];

    return FutureBuilder<List<LangModel>>(
      future: langProvider.loadLangs(), // <= exception occurs here
      initialData: langs,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 50),
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(
              leading: const CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/img/us.webp')),
              title: Text(snapshot.data.language),
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined),
              onTap: (){
                final route = MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const ScanPageScreen()
                );
                Navigator.push(context, route);
              },
            ),
            // separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**home_screen.dart**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: const [
          Logo(),
          LangList()
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
```

**lang_model.dart**

```
class LangModel {
    LangModel({
        required this.id,
        required this.flag,
        required this.language,
    });

    int id;
    Uint8List flag;
    String language;

    factory LangModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LangModel(
        id: json["id"],
        flag: json["flag"],
        language: json["language"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "flag": flag,
        "language": language,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `loadLangs` to this:

```
Future loadLangs<LangModel>() async{
    final langs = await getAllLangs();
    this.langs = [...langs];
  }
```

and then your FutureBuilder to this:

```
FutureBuilder(// remove the generic
  future: langProvider.loadLangs(),
      initialData: langs,
)
```

**second way**:
just pass `langProvider.getAllLangs()` to your FutureBuilder.

also change you lang_list.dart to this:

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: langProvider.loadLangs(),
      initialData: langs,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator(); // add this
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 50),
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) => ListTile(
              leading: const CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/img/us.webp')),
              title: Text(snapshot.data?[i].language?? ''), // add this
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_outlined),
              onTap: (){
                final route = MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const ScanPageScreen()
                );
                Navigator.push(context, route);
              },
            ),
            // separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I implement your suggestions but I get this error:

The getter 'language' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: language
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<dynamic>

Comment: could you please add LangModel code?

Comment: i'd publish de LangModel at the end of the main topic

Comment: after your new recommend, I get the original error: The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<LangModel>>?' in this line -> future: langProvider.loadLangs()

Comment: sorry my bad, i forgot to remove generic (<List<LangModel>>) from FutureBuilder in my last update.

Comment: It doesn't work too :( ... this is the error after apply the changes: Class 'List<LangModel>' has no instance getter 'language'.

Comment: because snapshot.data is a list. you should use it like this: Text(snapshot.data?[i].language?? '')

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `getAllLangs` based on your Future.

```
  future: langProvider.getAllLangs(),
```